# Make it so only people with certain role can use command. In discord.js v12+

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that sends a message if you use a command in the non-command channel it tells you to only use commands in the correct channel, but I want it not to affect people with the Staff role here is my code i am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null`
My code:

```
client.on('message', message => {

if(!message.member.roles.cache.has(784236433975541771)) {

  if (message.content.startsWith("-")) {
  if (message.channel.id === '759066524605612108') return;
  if (message.channel.id === '775035651640918067') return;
  if (message.channel.id === '777287305580511262') return;
    message.channel.send('You have been pinged in the <#759066524605612108> channel with the results to your command. Please only use commands there.');
  }else
  if (message.content.startsWith("!")) {
  if (message.channel.id === '759066524605612108') return;
  if (message.channel.id === '775035651640918067') return;
  if (message.channel.id === '777287305580511262') return;
    message.channel.send('Rank has been disabled in this channel. Please only use commands in the <#759066524605612108> channel.');
  }
}
});
```

I am trying to do this is discord.js v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone finds this and is looking for the answer i used
`let allowedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Staff");`
and that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this to allow members with certain roles to use your commands:

```
let allowedRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Staff");
if (message.member.roles.has(allowedRole.id) {
    // allowed access to command
} else { //aka members who arent staff 
   // not allowed access
}
```

Comment: Now im getting `TypeError: message.guild.roles.find is not a function`

Comment: It should be `message.guild.roles.cache.find()`

Comment: Yeah i forgot the cache, my b

Comment: ok thanks got it to work using this
`let allowedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Staff");`